# Extend ActiveCell-Range with LastRow

Tags: excel, vba, range

I've got some issues getting this range / function to work and would highly appreciate any comment before I enrage and throw it all out of the window.

```
Cells.Find(What:="**Some Search Term**", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _ 
xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
xlNext, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
r3 = ActiveCell.Row
c3 = ActiveCell.Column
```

With that I'm trying to fill a Range that later on will be filed with already copied values

```
Range("I & (r3 + 3):J & VeryLastRow2").Select
activesheet.Paste
```

using the following for defining the VeryLastRow2 (+1 for naming):

```
Dim VeryLastRow2 As Long
With activesheet
    VeryLastRow2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With
```

I've no idea why this isn't working.

Also I'm open for other suggestions. If needed to know - the data is in the middle of an sheet (always in Columns I+J) but with variable row count to the last row.

Comment: It is your concatenation syntax

Comment: try changing Range("I & (r3 + 3):J & VeryLastRow2"). to Range("I" & (r3 + 3) & ":J" & VeryLastRow2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your variables inside the quotes and they are not being evaluated, but put in as text.

```
Range("I & (r3 + 3):J & VeryLastRow2").Select
```

This evaluates to Range name I & (r3 + 3):J & VeryLastRow2,
You need to seperate your text from your variables like:

```
Range("I" & (r3 + 3) & ":J" & VeryLastRow2).Select
```

Thus when r3 = say 8 and verylastrow2 = 2000, your range will be I11:J2000

Comment: I could cry over my stupidity. I had it correct for the copy process but didn't follow-up for paste.... Big Thanks